# Memory Swapping and OS freeze

Tags: windows-7, macos, memory, freeze, memory-limit

In one scenario my written application uses more memory than available on a machine (which has 16GB). On OSX everything seems to work as expected and the OS still runs even hitting the memory barrier. On Windows the OS starts to freeze and I would like to clarify whats going on behind the scenes. My application runs in user-mode so I would expect just a massive slowdown of my application. But why does my OS freeze? The OS threads and memory should have a higher precedence and the OS should at least not stuck forever. I use Win 7 for this test and haven't tried it on Windows 8 or 10 yet. How would be your debugging approaches? Any resources you recommend that would also help me trying to understand this?

Comment: Do you have any antivirus or other security software that hooks disk accesses? try to disable it. I never had an OS freeze (could still move the mouse and start up resource monitor) when swapping heavily in Windows 7. You can also try to lower the priority of your process with Process Explorer which should result in no slowdown of any other apps you are running, making debugging easier.

Comment: What are you using? F#, Java, C? What is your editor, is it capable to debug at all? What are you writing - desktop, web, USB-interfaced micro-controllers? Any or all of these are might be related, especially if what you are using is interpreted and not a compiled code. I am not a programmer, but I know that interpreted code rely on a higher stack of memory management than compiled code, so there might be your answer and your tools to understand your issues - especially on cross-platform.

Comment: It's a desktop application written in C++and I use VS2012. The process is 'Below Normal 6'. It still freezes when turned to 'Background: 4' but just for a minute though then I can quit the process via taskmgr. The peak of virtual memory bytes is at 32 GB on a machine with 16 GB memory.

Comment: Ah, API - OSx terminates GUIs differently from Windows, your call to exit(), if any, might be the culprit. Again, the last time I programmed in curly brackets was back in the 1990s. These days I only script.